# How to find what branch the current branch tracks

Tags: git

I am trying to figure out what branch will be fetched if I do `git fetch` in the current branch, and how can I change that (by some variant of `git remote` or editing `.git/config` file).

From what remote branch `git pull` fetches the contents? Is it the same from which `git fetch` fetches the contents? Is there a git command which can show me all this information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To set up the tracked remote branch for a local branch use

```
git branch --set-upstream <local_branch> <remote_branch>
```

So, if you want your local `master` to track `origin/master`, type

```
git branch --set-upstream master origin/master
```

However, `git fetch` fetches all branches of the configured remote.

If you have multiple remotes (e.g. `origin` and `other`),

```
git fetch other
```

will fetch the remote `other` while

```
git fetch origin
```

will fetch `origin`.

To find out which remote branch is being tracked, open `.git/config` and search for an entry like

```
[branch "mybranch"]
  remote = <remote_name>
  merge = <remote_branch>
```

This tells you that your local branch `mybranch` has `<remote_name>` as configured remote and that it tracks `<remote_branch>` on `<remote_name>`.

Which branches are fetched from a remote and how they are called in your local repo is defined in the following section of `.git/config`:

```
[remote "origin"]
  fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
  url=<url_of_origin>
```

This tells you that the branches stored under `refs/heads` of your origin get fetched and get stored under `refs/remotes/origin/` in your local repo.

If you are on `mybranch` and type `git fetch`, the revisions of `<remote_name>` (specified in the `[remote <remote_name>]` section) will be fetched. If you type `git pull`, after fetching the revisions of `<remote_name>` the branch `<remote_branch>` of `<remote_name>` will be merged into `mybranch`.

Additional information can be found on the man pages of [`git branch`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html), [`git fetch`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html) and [`git pull`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html).

Comment: I was looking for the information about remote branches, and your last paragraph (suggestion to look into .git/config) is very very helpful. Do you know what 

    [remote "origin"]
      fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

mean (in my .git/config)? Does `git fetch` bring all branches of the form origin/refs/heads/xyz into local remote-tracking branches refs/remotes/origin/xyz? Does it happen for all xyz or only the current branch (in which `git fetch` is issued)?

Comment: This is great. A small edit: If you are on `mybranch` and type `git fetch`, the revisions of `<remote_name>` _specified in [remote <remote_name>] section_ will be fetched. I think that is correct, right?

Comment: I cannot say `@eckes` for some reason. It is automatically removed! :-(